# Why in the first print it says different while a and b are indentical?

Tags: java

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] a={1,2,3};
        int[] b={1,2,3};
        int[] c=a;
        String s="Neanderthal";
        String s2="Neanderthal";
        String s3=s;
        System.out.println((a.equals(b))?"Same":"Different");
        System.out.println((a.equals(c))?"Same":"Different");
        System.out.println((s.equals(s2))?"Same":"Different");
        System.out.println((s.equals(s3))?"Same":"Different");

    }
}
```

The 1st system.out.print returns the value different and i cannot see a reason for this, and all the others are the same. Please help me understand this

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `String`s which are compared for equality character-by-character <sup>*</sup>, Java arrays are compared only for reference equality. You need to use [`Array.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int[],%20int[]%29) or `Array.deepEquals` to do the comparison:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(a, b) ? "Same" : "Different");
```

<sup>*</sup> Since your code uses string literals, `s` and `s2` would refer to the same object instance. However, this is not critical to understanding the issue at hand, because interning is not applicable to arrays.

Comment: There's more to it than that in this case - even with `==`, the OP would get the same results due to string interning.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right, of course. I did not want to bring interning into the answer to avoid an "information overload" on the readers. I added a footnote with a hint for the OP that there is more to his question than the unexpected output.

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
    int[] a={1,2,3};
    int[] b={1,2,3};
```

`a` is pointing to an array, `b` is pointing to another array. Both the arrays are not same in the memory. That is, they both are pointing to different memory locations.Like :

`a`------------->|mem_loc_1|

`b`------------->|mem_loc_2|

Hence, `equals()` method tells you that both references are **NOT** pointing to same object.

Whereas when you say `c= a;`, the situation is :

`a` -------------> |mem_loc_1| <---------------- `c`

Hence `equals()` tells you that **YES**, `a` and `c` references reference to same objects.

Conclusion, when you say `c = a;` there are TWO references, but a single object in the memory.

P.S. Sorry for the bad graphical representation,just wanted to simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

because it doesn't do deep equals and does just shallow equals, Use [`Arrays.deepEquals();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]%29) to get expected output

Answer (score 0):

Before understanding above concept you need to note few things :

- equals() method is defined in Object class, and any class can
  override it.
- By default equals() method use memory address of objects to compare  them.
- So, if you do not overriding it then it will call  Object's method.
- String class has overridden version of equals() method.

Now come on your program :

In first print statement you are comparing two different object which has not overridden equals() method, so it use Object's method and obviously it check memory address which is different.

In second print statement two reference variable refer same object so its address are same and equals() method return true.

In other print statements for string, which has overridden equals() method, so it will check only actual (here string value) content of object it doesn't matter two String reference variable referring same object or different.